# How to include related entities when getting ApplicationUser from DB?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I am using ASP.NET MVC, Identity2. I have added a custom property (address) to `ApplicationUser`:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<long, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
{
    public long? ProfileAddressId { get; set; }

    // note that address is not virtual
    [ForeignKey("ProfileAddressId")]
    public Address ProfileAddress { get; set; }
}
```

`Address`, is a separate table, that I have in my DB.

Now in my controller, I want to get the user (and load it's address):

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    var applicationUserManager = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId<long>();

    // this does not load address
    var user = applicationUserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId<long>());

}
```

`Address` is not `virtual`, and I have disabled lazy loading in `ApplicationDbContext`:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, CustomRole, long, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext() 
        : base("myDB")
    {
        // Lazy loading is enabled by default - disable lazy loading
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }
    // more code...
 }
```

I don'w know why `Address` is not being loaded?

How can I extend `ApplicationUserManager` to include address? Or would it be possible to configure EF to always eager load related entities?